# PHP 4: Can not understand the OOP behaviour

Tags: php, oop, class, object, php4

While practicing for certification, I came across one MCQ the question. It was as below.

Q: Consider the following script. What will it output?

```
<?php
$global_obj = null;
class my_class
{
   var $value;
   function my_class()
   {
      global $global_obj;
      $global_obj = &$this;
   }
}
$a = new my_class;
$a->my_value = 5;
$global_obj->my_value = 10;
echo $a->my_value;
?>
```

Choose Right One
**Options:**

- A. 5
- B. 10
- C. Nothing
- D. The constructor will throw an error
- E. 510

I chose and B: 10 as because in `my_class` constructor `$global_obj` is being initialized by the reference of `$this`. By when I cross checked **my answer was wrong**

**As a description they mentioned that**

This is a really tricky one. Upon first examination, it would seem that the constructor of
`my_class` stores a reference to itself inside the `$global_obj variable`. Therefore, one would
expect that, when we later change the value of `$global_obj->my_value` to 10, the corresponding
value in $a would change as well. Unfortunately, the new operator does not return a reference,
but a copy of the newly created object. Therefore, the script will output 5 and the correct
answer is A.

---

Ya I agree the description is well enough but still I am not able to digest it as because we have clearly assigned `$global_obj` the reference of $this then how can be this possible? Can any one please explain in detail?

Comment: You are practicing for a *PHP 4* certification...? :)

Comment: Why would you want to get a PHP 4 certification? Seems like a waste of time and money when we are now on PHP 5.4.

Comment: I guess that is still useful in India where they get quite a lot of outsourced maintainance jobs on existing projects (I worked in Bangalore a couple of years for an IT company).

Comment: It's hard to tell which error/exception in this terribly-written example will trigger first, but the most glaring thing is that the class has no property called `my_value`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> we have clearly assigned $global_obj the reference of $this then how can be this possible?

You assign the global variable **within** the constructor. At that time, you are referencing kind of a temporary object. Then the constructor returns a **copy** of that temporary object. This is that copy that $a will reference (whereas the global var still references the temporary object).

Going OOP with php 4 is nuts. I guess you should not understand the OOP behaviour of PHP 4 but just accept it...

Comment: Thank you Marvin, Exam preparation insisting to understand PHP 4 OOP's behavior. In turn, actually to understand the OOP's differences between PHP 4 and PHP 5. The word "temporary Object" does the magic here. Actually I was so confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this script will output "5" which would be A along with the following warning Warning: Creating default object from empty value

the reason for this is when you set this

```
                 `$global_obj = &$this;`
```

what your assigning is reference to the current object

this article may help

http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/02/25/why-do-some-php-variables-have-an-ampersand-before-them/